# How to select multiple column with one column being max() from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sybase

```
select max(some_column1), some_column2 from(
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table1 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table1)
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table2 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table2) 
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table3 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table3)
) as max_result
```

This query does exactly what I want. The only problem is when I get the max result from some_column1 I also want to get some_column2 that is corresponds to max(some_column1). Instead I get 3 results. I need to limit it to one result. some_column2 has to be from the same table as max(some_column1). Is there anyway to do this besides storing the result into a temp table?
All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to sort by some_column1 and take the first row.  This will get the row where some_column1 has the bigger value and still has access to some_column2.

Try:

```
select top 1 some_column1, some_column2 from(
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from @table1 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from @table1)
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from @table2 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from @table2) 
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from @table3 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from @table3)
) as max_result
order by some_column1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot..Its a bit convoluted...but should work..If there is a tie in max values, and you want all of then, then just replace the `=` check in where clause with `IN`

```
select max_result.some_column1,max_result.some_column2 from (
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table1 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table1)
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table2 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table2) 
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table3 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table3)
) max_result
where max_result.some_column1 =
(select max(some_column1) from
(
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table1 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table1)
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table2 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table2) 
    union all
    select distinct some_column1, some_column2 from table3 where some_column1 = (select max(some_column1) from table3)
))
```